# Change WSDL definition generated by JBoss from JAX-WS annotations in my code?

Tags: java, jboss, wsdl, definition

I am developing a Web services in Java using JbossWS.

The WS is pretty simple. Something like this:

```
@WebService(targetNamespace="http://www.huawei.com/schema/syncorder/v1-0/", name="SyncOrderRelationExt")
public interface ISyncOrderRelation {

  @WebMethod
  public int SyncOrderRelationExt(String SPID, String productID, String serviceID);
```

And implementation

```
@WebService(portName="SyncOrderRelationExtHttpPort", serviceName="SyncOrderRelationExt", targetNamespace="http://www.huawei.com/schema/syncorder/v1-0/")
    public class SyncOrderRelation implements ISyncOrderRelation
    {


       public int SyncOrderRelationExt(String SPID, String productID, String serviceID) 
       {
            return 0;
       }

    }
```

Everything seems to work fine.. but now calling this WS from .NET proyect, I have to make someting like this:

```
 SyncOrderRelationExt syncNTS = new SyncOrderRelationExt();            

 var params= new SyncOrderRelationExt1()
 {
        arg1 = "a",
        arg2 = "b",
        arg3 = "c",               
 };

 var res = syncNTS.CallSyncOrderRelationExt(params);

 int x = res.@return;
```

Buy I would like to call the WS in this way (requirements):

```
SyncOrderRelationExt sync = new SyncOrderRelationExt(); 

int res2 =  sync.CallSyncOrderRelationExt("a", "b", "c");
```

is there any way to change the definition in Java for get the client call different?

Thank you very much in advance.